# Spring Model - "Model object must not be null"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4

A method in one of my Spring controller class,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{productId}/specifications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setup(@PathVariable("productId") Integer pid, Model m) {
  //... 
  m.addAttribute(foo);  <-- error
  return "my-page";
}
```

After I got an error message "Model object must not be null", I change the method signature as shown in the following:
        public ModelAndView setup(@PathVariable("productId") Integer pid) {

```
    //...
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("my-page");
    mv.addObject(foo);     <-- error

    return mv; 
}
```

I was able to run the modified code once. But I got the same error on ModelAndView. I have used Spring MVC for many years. That is my first time having this problem. What is the cause?

I use Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE.

Comment: Is the `foo` reference a null reference?  Your code snippets do not show how anything about what the `foo` reference is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not provided the code that shows what the `foo` reference points to, it is safe to assume it is a null reference.

I took a look at the Project code on Github, and it is clear what happening here.

The [ModelAndView#addObject(Object)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.java) method delegates to the [ModelMap#addAttribute(Object)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.java) method, which asserts that the provided `Object` is not null, using the exact message your question is asking about.

`ModelAndView` method:

```
public ModelAndView addObject(Object attributeValue) {
    getModelMap().addAttribute(attributeValue);
    return this;
}
```

`ModelMap` method:

```
public ModelMap addAttribute(Object attributeValue) {
    Assert.notNull(attributeValue, "Model object must not be null");
    if (attributeValue instanceof Collection && ((Collection<?>) attributeValue).isEmpty()) {
        return this;
    }
    return addAttribute(Conventions.getVariableName(attributeValue), attributeValue);
}
```